# Composer requiring password for update

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, cpanel, centos6

PHP Composer update statements require a user password on a particular server, but on all other servers (that appear to be configured the same) it does not. I would like to correct this so that composer no longer requires a password when we update.

**Background**

Our small business has several servers in a data center. We run CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 standard. Each server is running the latest cpanel/whm (WHM 58.0 (build 28)).

Web directories are tied to user names. So /home/user1 is the directory for the user1 user, and so on. (This is just a normal setup for CPanel CentOS servers).

**Updating composer**

Whenever a user logs in via SSH with their username, they can run `composer update --no-dev` in their home directory and everything gets updated. If we want, we can call composer update from a script that logs into the server and executes the command as well. This is the normal and expected path.

**The problem server**

There is one server that behaves differently. When we run `composer update --no-dev` on this server, it asks for the local user's password. I believe this is running just the default CPanel install of Composer. This is a problem. We do not want it to request a password. This messes with our ability to automate the command. But we cannot figure out what is different about this server.

**Additional details on file permissions**

Composer is installed at /bin/ and the `ls -l` details as follows:

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1705467 Jul 19 14:43 composer*`

Just for comparison the `cat` command is in the same directory and the `ls -l` looks like this:

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    48568 May 11 03:59 cat*`

The `cat` command does not require a password, but the composer command does.

**Details about where composer is executed**

Composer is executed in the user directory.

All files are owned by the user. Files have permissions as follows: `-rw-r--r--` and directories have permissions as follows: `drwxr-xr-x`

Interestingly, the `.composer` directory is set as follows: `drwxrwxr-x` but that is the same across other servers as well.

**Comments**

Note on relevance: This appears to be related to PHP Composer setup (but like I said, we do not know exactly why this happens yet) since all other binaries and commands called in/from the same directories are working fine. Most of my description and question is setup to address the fact that the server appears to be configured correctly in order to eliminate many of those variables. Since this specifically affects the setup of a php tool, the topic seems more relevant on Stack Overflow than on Server Fault, therefore it is a relevant question for Stack Overflow.

Thank you again for your time and I would greatly appreciate if you have any insights at all into this!

Comment: Since the users are running `composer update` from their home folders, I'm guessing that they all have a `composer.json`-file in there? Is there anything different in that file, compared to the other servers? Like any `"scripts"` that might require sudo rights or similar?

Comment: There is a composer.json file. In fact this is an internally developed sourcecode that is copied to each user account, so each has their own copy of the code. The composer.json is identical to what is found on other servers.

Comment: Are they asked for the password for the server their on or for some remote the composer.json file uses?

Comment: It is the server that they are logged into... So for example, the user logs in via ssh (i.e. with a key)... Then after they have cleared the hurdle of logging in and are in their home directory, they issue the `composer update` command for the composer setup found in the local directory.

Comment: Very strange. Try to run `sudo composer self-update` and see if you just happen to have a buggy version? I know that I've managed to get buggy versions a couple of times. If that doesn't work... try to remove composer and install it again? Other than that, I'm stumped...

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions @MagnusEriksson, unfortunately, it did not work. I know what you mean, I've been stumped by this for over a month and finally thought maybe this is a question I should be asking a broader audience of experts. I've never run into this before and short of nuking the server and starting over (which I cannot do at the present time) I am completely stumped by this as well.  Thanks again for your troubleshooting ideas.